# How to create ratio table between two tables in R with different dimensions?

Tags: r

table1 output:

```
 <<<   <B0     0   010   011   030   072   080   122   132   1GT   89O   AFG   AGO   ALB   AND   ARE   ARG   ARM   AUS   AUT   AVN 
  1     2      2    1     1     1     1     1     2    10     1     2     2     3    25     1     2    66     7    458   392     1
```

table2 output:

```
 042  090  ALB  ARG  AUS  AUT  AZE 
  1    1    2    4   36   75    1
```

The aim is to combine the tables into one table of ratios for labels which exist in both tables. I am stumped, everything I try gives me dimension problems.

Desired output:

```
     ALB         ARG         AUS           AUT 
  2/(2+25)    4/(4+66)   36/(36+458)   75/(75+392)
```

Any ideas? Every method I try doesnt work >:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `intersect` on the `names`

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(table1), names(table2))
```

subset both of them and get the  ratio

```
table1[nm1]/(table1[nm1] + table2[nm1])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `stack` + `merge` like below

```
transform(
    merge(stack(v1), stack(v2), by = "ind"),
    ratio = values.y / (values.x + values.y)
)
```

which gives

```
  ind values.x values.y      ratio
1 ALB       25        2 0.07407407
2 ARG       66        4 0.05714286
3 AUS      458       36 0.07287449
4 AUT      392       75 0.16059957
```

## data

```
> dput(v1)
c(`<<<` = 1L, `<B0` = 2L, `0` = 2L, `010` = 1L, `011` = 1L, `030` = 1L, 
`072` = 1L, `080` = 1L, `122` = 2L, `132` = 10L, `1GT` = 1L,
`89O` = 2L, AFG = 2L, AGO = 3L, ALB = 25L, AND = 1L, ARE = 2L,
ARG = 66L, ARM = 7L, AUS = 458L, AUT = 392L, AVN = 1L)
> dput(v2)
c(`042` = 1L, `090` = 1L, ALB = 2L, ARG = 4L, AUS = 36L, AUT = 75L, 
AZE = 1L)
```